# Merging two lists in linq without anonymous type

Tags: c#, linq

I have: `var list = IEnumerable<MergedData>` where

```
public class MergedData
{
   public A A;
   public B B;
}

public class A
{
   public int Id;
   public string Value;
}

public class B
{
   public int Id;
   public string Value;
}
```

what can I do such that I end up with a list of a merged type with `A.Id, A.Value, B.Id, B.Value` *without* creating an anonymous type?

I would like the merging procedure to be independent of the specific types `A` and `B`.

Comment: Could you clarify what you want to do? What's your merging procedure? What are input/expected outputs?

Comment: You can start by creating an interface and making both `A` and `B` class implement it. Your merging procedure would then work with this interface type.

Comment: I think you should look at [how do I join two lists using linq or lambda expressions][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6253656/how-do-i-join-two-lists-using-linq-or-lambda-expressions

Comment: @LawrenceThurman The problem here is that I need to explicitly select what stuff I want.

Comment: What happens if no matching records are found? Or if there are duplicates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why cannot you use anonymous type?

```
var result = list.Select(item => new {
                           AId = item.A.Id, 
                           AValue = item.A.Value, 
                           BId = item.B.Id, 
                           BValue= item.B.Value});
```

What exactly would you need?

For example, the list with values A = {2, "2"} and B = {3,"3"}, A = {4, "4"} and B = {5,"5"}, what would be the expected result?

NOTE: If you want to have both in the same list, you could do something like this I think... (I haven't tested it)

```
var result = list.Select(item => new {
                           Id = item.A.Id, 
                           Value = item.A.Value 
                         }).ToList().AddRange(list.Select(item => new {
                           Id = item.B.Id, 
                           Value = item.B.Value 
                         });
```

However, you will still need to have the Id and Value in different fields. Do you also want both fields to be added in the same list?

Comment: Well, mainly because I in this `list.Select()` I will have to know the exact structure of the anonymous type.

Comment: Sorry, I think I don't follow you. What would be the expected result for the example i wrote? maybe I can understand what you mean then..

Answer (score 1):

Even though I rather prefer the idea behind @Yumei De Armas answer. Just create a new class containing all the properties that you need and create new instances of this class. Something like:

```
public class MergedData
{
 public int AId;
 public string AValue;
 public int BId;
 public string BValue;
}
```

And in your LINQ you just use this class instead of anonymous object like :
 `..new MergedData { AId = some_value, AValue = some_value, BId = some_value, BValue = some_value}`

However, you already have the two classes in your `MergedData` class so if you insist on your design then you should complicate the syntax a little more:

`..new MergedData { new A { Id = some_value, Value = some value}, new B { Id = some_value, Value = some value}}`

Comment: What doesn't sit right with me, is the copying of variables. If my class gets big (and it does) and changes often (it does), I will have to write a `MergedData` for every time it changes instead of automagically just taking everything.

Comment: @lejon Ok, maybe I don't get you right. Do you have your `A` and `B` objects already instantiated and populated with the values you want from somewhere else (like web view for example) and you just want to create `MergedData` objects using the already created `A` and `B` objects. In other words at what point you get `A` and `B` objects created and populated?

Comment: I have `List<A>` and `List<B>` already instantiated and what I want to do is to flatten them.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to make your question more clear - especially regarding the expected output.  Here's my interpretation:

```
public class MergedData<T,T2>
{
   public T A;
   public T2 B;
   public MergedData(T A, T2 B)
   {
       this.A = A;
       this.B = B;   
   }
}

public class A
{
   public int Id;
   public string Value;
}

public class B
{
   public int Id;
   public string Value;
}

 var listOfMerged = new List<MergedData<A,B>>();
 for (int i=0; i<listOfA.Count; i++)
     listOfMerged.Add(new MergedData<A,B> (listOfA[i],listOfB[i]));

 //  Example of Use
 var merged = listOfMerged[0];
 Console.WriteLine(merged.A.Id);
 Console.WriteLine(merged.B.Value);
```

If this is along the lines of what you want, I'd take a look at the [Tuple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) type.