# Set a property from a List A according to a property from List B

Tags: c#, wpf, list

I have two lists:
`List<UserModel>` and `List<UserDetails>`

Where:

```
public class UserModel
{
    public int RoleId { get; private set; }
    public IEnumerable<UserType> UserType
    {
        get { return Enum.GetValues(typeof(UserType)).Cast<UserType>(); }
    }

    private UserType selectedUserType;
    public UserType SelectedUserType
    {
        get { return selectedUserType; }
        set
        {
           .....
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
public class UserDetails
{
    public bool IsPrimary { get; set; }
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

I need to set  `bool IsPrimary` from `UserDetails` to `true`, if `SelectedUserType` is set to `Primary`, but only for the same `RoleId`... `UserType` is an `Enum : Primary, Secondary`.

So, how can i do this? Any idea?

Comment: Neither of them `UserModel` or `UserDetails` is a `List`, those are `class`es, and what is the relation between the `classes`? this is totally unclear.

Comment: Create a `relation` between two `classes` and when setting the `property` write a `linq/ lambda expression` to set other property with the relation.

Comment: First list is  type of UserModel. Second list is type of  UserDetails,  I don't have a relationship between them because i can't. It's a little more complicated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate them by their RoleID as the following:

```
List<UserModel> models = ...;
List<UserDetails> details = ...;

models.Foreach(x => details
    .Where(y => y.RoleId == x.RoleId)
    .ToList()
    .Foreach(y => y.IsPrimary = (x.SelectedUserType == UserType.Primary))
);
```

What it does is iterating the `UserModels`, than foreach `UserModel` iterating all of the `UserDetails` and filtering those who have the same `RoleId`, than for them setting `IsPrimary` to `true` only if `SelectedUserType` of the matching `UserModel` is `UserType.Primary`.

This also can be done without Linq like the following:

```
List<UserModel> models = ...;
List<UserDetails> details = ...;

foreach (UserModel model in models)
{
    foreach (UserDetails detail in details)
    {
        if (detail.RoleId == model.RoleId)
        {
            bool isPrimary = model.SelectedUserType == UserType.Primary;
            detail.IsPrimary = isPrimary;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider joining the two lists using LINQ expressions. Convert the result of the join function (which also should be filtered based on UserType) to a new list and loop through all the elements and set the boolean to true.

Check out the [following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6253656/how-do-i-join-two-lists-using-linq-or-lambda-expressions).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. To join two lists according to a property that is common for both lists, is simple. But how to set  that bool if selectedUserType is Primary, only for the same RoleId..?

Comment: you can convert the result of the join function (which also should be filtered based on UserType) to a new list and loop through all the elements and set the boolean to true

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have an `IEnumerable<UserModel>` and an `IEnumerable<UserDetails>`. I've changed the classes a bit to simplify the question.

```
var userDetails = new List<UserDetails>{ 
    new UserDetails(){ Id = 1, RoleId = 1 },
    new UserDetails(){ Id = 2, RoleId = 1 },
    new UserDetails(){ Id = 3, RoleId = 2 },
    new UserDetails(){ Id = 4, RoleId = 2 }
};

var userModels = new List<UserModel> {
    new UserModel { RoleId = 1, SelectedUserType = UserType.Primary },
    new UserModel { RoleId = 2, SelectedUserType = UserType.Secondary },
    new UserModel { RoleId = 3, SelectedUserType = UserType.Primary }
};
```

Then, you need to set IsPrimary to true of UserDetails 1 and 2, correct?

```
var userDetailsToSetPrimary = 
    (from userDetail in userDetails
    join userModel in userModels
    on userDetail.RoleId equals userModel.RoleId
    where userModel.SelectedUserType == UserType.Primary
    select userDetail);

foreach(userDetail in userDetailsToSetPrimary)
    userDetail.IsPrimary = true;
```