# Combining two lists and overwriting some of the values

Tags: c#

I have two lists of this class for example `List1`, `List2`

```
public class SearchCriteriaOption
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public bool selected { get; set; }
    public bool required { get; set; }
    public int sortOrder { get; set; }
}
```

`List1` always has equal or more items in it than `List2`. List2 is pretty much a subset of List1

The primary key is that '`id`' property.

I want to create a third list out of these two lists such that it will have all the items of `List1` **BUT** for the items that have **the same id in both lists**, use property values from `List1` **EXCEPT** for **selected** and "**sortOrder**" property, use **List2** for that. 
I can't think of a way to start approaching this. So I need some help.

Comment: I would suggest Linq and there is a good post already that will explain how to join the lists. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723985/linq-join-2-listts and here is another post that gives better details regarding using properties from both to create a new object. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6253656/how-do-i-join-two-lists-using-linq-or-lambda-expressions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var List3 = List1
    .GroupJoin(List2,
        o1 => o1.id, o2 => o2.id,
        (option1, option2) => new { option1, option2 })
    .SelectMany(
        x => x.option2.DefaultIfEmpty(),
        (x, option2) => new SearchCriteriaOption
        {
            // use most properties from list1
            id = x.option1.id,
            description = x.option1.description,
            name = x.option1.name,
            required = x.option1.required,

            // using list2 for selected and sortOrder if available
            // (if you cant use C# 6 syntax, use the next 2 lines)
            //selected = option2 != null ? option2.selected : x.option1.selected,
            //sortOrder = option2 != null ? option2.sortOrder : x.option1.sortOrder,
            selected = option2?.selected ?? x.option1.selected,
            sortOrder = option2?.sortOrder ?? x.option1.sortOrder,
        })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Should it be Union or Join? Because with this example I got 2 items in my List3 but I should have got 10 item because my main list which is List1 had 10 items, my smaller List2 had 2 items.

Comment: Sorry, i read you wanted to create a third list "for the items that have the same id in both lists". My bad, i'll fix it.

Comment: @Bohn I've changed inner join to left join