# How do you select the parent(s) based on child properties?

Tags: ef-core-3.1

My Parent (movies) have child collections on them (actors), how do I select all the movies that have Actor A and Actor B or even Actor C etc...? I can do manage a simple query to find all Actor A movies etc...but doing (n) Actors seems unclear.  My model is below:

```
    public class Movie
    {
        public int MovieID { get; set; }

        public string MovieTitle { get; set; }
        
        public ICollection<MovieActor> MovieActors { get; set; }
    }

public class MovieActor
    {
        public int MovieID { get; set; }
        public Movie Movie { get; set; }

        public int ActorID { get; set; }
        public Actor Actor { get; set; }
    }

 public class Actor
    {
        public int ActorID { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("First Name")]
        public string ActorFirstname { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Last Name")]
        public string ActorLastname { get; set; }

        public ICollection<MovieActor> MovieActors { get; set; }
        
    }
```

My dbContext config for that object looks like this:

```
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<MovieActor> builder)
        {
            builder.HasKey(ma => new { ma.MovieID, ma.ActorID });
            builder.HasOne(ma => ma.Movie)
                .WithMany(m => m.MovieActors)
                .HasForeignKey(ma => ma.MovieID);
            builder.HasOne(ma => ma.Actor)
                .WithMany(a => a.MovieActors)
                .HasForeignKey(ma => ma.ActorID);
        }
```

Comment: use join query, you should join movie list and actor list then select movies contain specific actors. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/join-clause

Comment: also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6253656/how-do-i-join-two-lists-using-linq-or-lambda-expressions

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want movies that have the specified actors in the same movie, you can do this.

```
    private List<Movie> GetMovies(params int[] actorIds)
    {
        IQueryable<Movie> movies = dc.Movies;

        foreach (int actorId in actorIds)
        {
            movies = movies.Where(w => w.MovieActors.Any(a => a.ActorId == actorId));
        }

        return movies.ToList();
    }
```

or if you're wanting all movies that any of those actors have been in

```
     return dc
            .MovieActors
            .Where(w => actorIds.Contains(w.ActorId))
            .Select(s => s.Movie)
            .Distinct()
            .ToList();
```

There are many ways to access the data, not saying these are the best performance wise but they do give you options.